# Php For Loop giving an extra iteration

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to figure something out here.

I have an unserialized array containing multiple choice questions coming out of the database into a dropdown.

I need this to loop through so when the person submits the answers, the grading page needs to know how many loops it needs to count through to pick up the correct vs incorrect answers.

My issue is that it is counting through a test question one extra time, and giving a false result at the end.  Saying "you got 2 questions right" when there was only one question, for example.

Here is the array printed from the database, that the test taker sees before submitting the answer.

```
<form class="create-test" action="grade.php" method="POST">



 <?php
    $numberOfLoops = 1;
    foreach ($testArray as $testArray['row']) {
        //echo  $testArray['row']['choice1'];

    //}
    //for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++){
    ?>
        <label for='test-question'><?php echo $testArray['row']['question']; ?></label>

        <!-- Loop to go through the question array from the database, to be posted to the grading funciton -->
        <select class = 'form-control' name="Question<?php echo $numberOfLoops; ?>">
          <option value="Select an answer" disable selected hidden>Select an answer</option> 
          <option value="<?php echo $testArray['row']['choice1']; ?>"><?php echo $testArray['row']['choice1']; ?></option>
          <option value="<?php echo $testArray['row']['choice2']; ?>"><?php echo $testArray['row']['choice2']; ?></option>
          <option value="<?php echo $testArray['row']['choice3']; ?>"><?php echo $testArray['row']['choice3']; ?></option>
        </select> 

        <input type="hidden" class='form-control' id='actanswer' name="actanswer<?php echo $numberOfLoops; ?>"  value="<?php echo $testArray['row']['answer']; ?>">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <?php
            $numberOfLoops++;
        }

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='numberOfLoops' value='".$numberOfLoops."'>";
    ?>
    <input type='hidden' name='test-id' value="<?echo $testID; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name='submit-answers'>Submit Answers</button>
</form>
```

And here is the for loop that looks for the answers.

```
  $correct = 0;
    $incorrect = 0;

    $num = $_POST['numberOfLoops'];

echo $num;

for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
    $response = $_POST['Question'.$x];
    echo $response."<br>";
    $answer = $_POST['actanswer'.$x];
    echo $answer."<br>";
    if($answer == $response){
        $correct++;


    }elseif($response !== $answer){
        $incorrect++;
    }


}
```

It will always count one extra, no matter how many questions there are.

All help and feedback appreciated.

EDIT:  As a further bit of information, there is an echo tag that will say you got x right and y incorrect.  If the test is two questions long, it will say.  "You got 3 questions right, and 0 wrong."  Even though there's only two questions.

Comment: Show us `test array`

Comment: This looks dangerous `foreach ($testArray as $testArray['row'])` Why not do a simple `foreach ($testArray as $row)` and avoid messing up your input array

Comment: $testArray is declared as the unserialized test that was saved into a table containing more than the test.  Are you saying, after it's unserialized, to declare $row = ['row']?

Answer (score 1):

Dont do this

```
foreach ($testArray as $testArray['row']) {
```

This is creating a new occurance in the `$testArray` and probably explains your extra iteration.

Instead try

```
foreach ($testArray as $row) {
```

and amend the code that follows this line to use `$row['choice1']` etc etc

EXAMPLE:

```
$sessions = [ 'a','b'];
foreach ( $sessions as $sessions['row']) {
    echo $sessions['row'].PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($sessions);
```

Will output:

```
a
b
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [row] => b
)
```

Comment: I agree with this for the most part, but using `$testArray['row']` doesn't cause an extra iteration because foreach iterates over a copy of the array, and isn't affected by changes to the orignal array.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You made me think, so I checked it. This adds the `row` occurance to the original array.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does, I just meant that that new key won't be included in the foreach iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the main explanation for what you're seeing:

```
$numberOfLoops = 1;
```

Then you increment it for each question. So `$numberOfLoops` is always going to be one more than the number of questions. Then in the continuation condition for your `for` loop, you have

```
$x <= $num
```

So if you have two questions, for example, `$numberOfLoops` will be 3, and the loop will execute three times.